# Creating social graph via twitter4j

Tags: java, graph, twitter, twitter4j

i would like to create social graph based on users and followers from Twitter.
I'm using twitter4j library. I'm iterating over graph starting from selected user and then i'm getting his followers, then recursively function is executed for his followers. The problem is i receive rate limit very quickly.

```
public void getFollowers(Twitter twitter, String twitterScreenName)
{
    try
    {           
        IDs followerIDs = twitter.getFollowersIDs(twitterScreenName, -1);
        long [] followerIdList = followerIDs.getIDs();
        if (followerIdList.length > 0)
        {
            String screenName = "";
            for(long id: followerIdList)
            {
                twitter4j.User user = twitter.showUser(id);
                screenName = user.getScreenName();
                System.out.println("Name: " + screenName);
                getFollowers(twitter, screenName);
            }

        }
    }
    catch(TwitterException e)
    {            
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The result is unsatisfactory because i can't get deeper to followers of user followers and so on. I know i could wait 15 minutes and again restore program working but it would last too long and graph is very poor.
Is it another way to bypass that problem or other tools similar to twitter4j which can solve problem of creating graph? Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, this is a restriction placed by Twitter itself. You are going to have to limit this somehow.

Comment: so it is impossible to create large graph this way in 
reasonable time?

Comment: I think this is intended, it's a shared service by Twitter. Otherwise, People would and could load the whole dataset and consume all resources. For any other analysis, a dump can by purchased from Twitter or one might to use older dumps form academic projects maybe

Comment: Such a graph might be possible if you're willing to pay Twitter for an increased rate limit. But if not, then no, not possible.

Comment: According to the documentation at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids you can request 15 times in 15 minutes, so you should "sleep" for 60 secs between each request.

Comment: Thank you for help, i read about it in documentation but for creating graph in my way it is much too long. More interesting for me is how to change algorithm for quick creating social graph or maybe you know other legal sources of complete datasets?

Comment: There are no "complete" datasets, that's almost impossible in Twitter - it will always be outdated. As already said, you can purchase data and use the *enterprise API* - that said, it's clear that anything beyond can't be free at least not on a legal way. There are indeed some historical datasets, though incomplete.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with the data, and which part of the data exactly you're interested in. so any further suggestion is difficult

Comment: Twitter’s Developer Policy (which you agree to when you get keys for the Twitter API) places limits on the sharing of datasets. If you are sharing datasets of tweets, you can only publicly share the ids of the tweets, not the tweets themselves. Another party that wants to use the dataset has to retrieve the complete tweet from the Twitter API based on the tweet id (“hydrating”). Any tweets which have been deleted or become protected will not be available.

Comment: Another option for acquiring an existing Twitter dataset is TweetSets, a web application. TweetSets allows you to create your own dataset by querying and limiting an existing dataset. For example, you can create a dataset that only contains original tweets with the term “trump” from the Women’s March dataset. If you are local, TweetSets will allow you to download the complete tweet; otherwise, just the tweet ids can be downloaded. Currently, TweetSets includes nearly a half billion tweets.

Comment: I did not express myself well saying "complete" dataset. My goal is to study effectivity of community detection algorithms which are applied in Neo4j. Their work is based on graph structure so "complete" dataset is not necessary. I'll check TweetSets then, maybe i can find some interesting data.